# Python 27 - BeautifulSoup and Tables

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I have this source:

```
<tr id="bitstampUSD">
<td class="arrow" change="up" latest_trade="1363480722">
  <span class="down">▼</span>
</td>

<td class="symbol">
    <nobr>
    <a href="/markets/bitstampUSD.html">bitstampUSD</a>
    </nobr>
    <span class="sub">USD (SEPA converted)</span>
</td>
<td>46.74
    <span class="sub">41 min ago</span>
</td>
<td class="minichart break">
  <span volume="**whole heaps of number here that I want**"
  print="**more numbers I want**"
  avg="**more numbers I want**"
  class="marketsparkline"></span>
</td>
<td>**36.39**

  <span class="sub change">**10.35 28.46%**</span>

</td>
<td>**141,043.10**
    <span class="sub">**5,132,052.22 USD**</span>
</td>
<td>**25.25**
    <span class="sub">**46.58** (24h)</span>
</td>
<td>**49.17**
    <span class="sub">47 (24h)</span>
</td>
<td class="break">**46.7**</td>
<td>**46.74**</td>
<td class="break">**46.78**

  <span class="sub change">-0.04 -0.09%</span>

</td>
<td>**819.54**
    <span class="sub">**38,340.96** USD</span>
</td>
      </tr>
```

So I want to get the data in bold. (Well, it's supposed to be in bold, I guess the code tags stop that from happening.  The data inside two asterisks.

I managed to figure out how to get the bits in code which I didn't include here, because it was inside the classes. But here, some of it is outside the classes so I don't know how to grab it.

It may help to look at the entire source, if you want http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/
It's laid out differently than other table code I've seen before.

Comment: Rather than fiddling with HTML parsing, wouldn't it be easier to use their [Markets API](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/)?  I just tried it myself and it returned a nice JSON-encoded list of dictionaries, with values like `[{u'volume': 822.42673038, u'latest_trade': 1363486862, u'bid': 46.81, u'high': 47.0, u'currency': u'USD', u'currency_volume': 38473.8713986671, u'ask': 46.83, u'close': 46.81, u'avg': 46.78091066044309, u'symbol': u'bitstampUSD', u'low': 46.58}]`.

Comment: Oh god damn it! haha  WEll, I would like to figure this out anyway, but if it fails I'll have a look at that, cheers.

Comment: Haidro - For some reason that returns a blank list.

Comment: @DSM Could you explain how to use that data?  I'm trying your way now using the API but I'm not sure how that can be used.  It's a massive clump of data, how do I distinguish which data belongs to which exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this outputs a bit more than you requested, but should get you started:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
for td in soup.find_all('td', class_='minichart break'):
    avg = td.span['avg']
    print_ = td.span['print']
    volume = td.span['volume']
    print avg, print_, volume

for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    print 'TD', td.text.split()
```

On your example I obtain:

```
**more numbers I want** **more numbers I want** **whole heaps of number here that I want**                                                                                                                                                                                         
[u'\u25bc']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[u'bitstampUSD', u'USD', u'(SEPA', u'converted)']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[u'46.74', u'41', u'min', u'ago']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[u'**36.39**', u'**10.35', u'28.46%**']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[u'**141,043.10**', u'**5,132,052.22', u'USD**']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[u'**25.25**', u'**46.58**', u'(24h)']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[u'**49.17**', u'47', u'(24h)']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[u'**46.7**']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[u'**46.74**']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[u'**46.78**', u'-0.04', u'-0.09%']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[u'**819.54**', u'**38,340.96**', u'USD']
```